# How to get all input inside a tr not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the information of all input inside a tr and I use this jquery to test how to do it but I can't manage to get it work.

```
<table>
<tr id="" class="line">
    <input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='rpiid' value='123' />
    <input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='sensor_id' value='1' />
    <input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='when' value='2014-02-24 05:00:03' />
    <td>Home
        <BR />2014-02-24
        <BR />05:00:03</td>
    <td>
        <input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val' value='761' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id='' class='' type='checkbox' name='train' value='True' checked />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id='' class='' type='checkbox' name='valid' value='True' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id='update' class='' type='' name='button' value='update' src=''>update</button>
        <button id='delete' class='' type='' name='button' value='delete' src=''>delete</button>
    </td>
    <td id="resultFromGet"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="" class="line">
    <input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='rpiid' value='456' />
    <input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='sensor_id' value='2' />
    <input id='' class='' type='hidden' name='when' value='2014-02-24 04:00:03' />
    <td>Home
        <BR />2014-02-24
        <BR />04:00:03</td>
    <td>
        <input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val' value='456' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id='' class='' type='checkbox' name='train' value='True' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id='' class='' type='checkbox' name='valid' value='True' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id='update' class='' type='' name='button' value='update' src=''>update</button>
        <button id='delete' class='' type='' name='button' value='delete' src=''>delete</button>
    </td>
    <td id="resultFromGet"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var button;
    var line;
    var inputs;
    $('button#update').click(function () {
        button = $(this);
        line = button.closest('.line');
        inputs = line.find('input');
        inputs.each(function (id, item) {
            alert(item.attr('name'));
        });
    });
});
```

I really don't understand what is wrong and how can I print all what is inside the var inputs to screen for debug purpose. I have tried also :

```
alert(JSON.stringify(inputs, null, 4));
```

But it doesn't give me anything :(.

Comment: id must be unique. `id=''` for all input is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
alert($(item).attr('name'));
```

instead of:

```
alert(item.attr('name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

ID of an element must be unique, you can use the button value  instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button[value=update]').click(function () {
        var button = $(this);
        var line = button.closest('.line');
        var inputs = line.find('input');
        inputs.each(function (id, item) {
            alert($(item).attr('name'));
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ELEY4/)

or instead of the ID set `update`/`delete` as the class name of buttons and use it as the selector

```
<button class='update' type='' name='button' value='update' src=''>update</button>
<button class='delete' type='' name='button' value='delete' src=''>delete</button>
```

then

```
$('button.update').click(function () {
    ...
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ELEY4/2/)

Also inside the each loop, `item` is a dom element, not a jQuery object so you have to use `$(item).attr()`

Comment: 'button[name=update]' is not working and i would brefer not using class. are you sure it is the proper way of writing it? I have tried putting just an alert('ok') on button click but nothing comes out in fiddle...

Comment: @user2040597 sorry, the name of all buttons is `button` instead use the value... I've updated the answer already

Answer (score 0):

First use class instead of id

```
<button class='update' type='' name='button' value='update' src=''>update</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var button;
    var line;
    var inputs;
    $('.update').click(function () {      
        button = $(this);
        line = $(this).parents('tr')

        inputs = line.find('input');
        inputs.each(function (id, item) {
            alert($(item).attr('name'));
        });
    });
});
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/kR9W4/2/